# How to find out if Android Studio is actually using the Intel HAXM accelerator?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Intel HAXM installed on my machine along with Atom image. When I fire-up emulator in Android Studio, don't see anything that would tell me if `Intel HAXM` is being utilized or not.

According to the screenshots on [Intel's website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture), in `Starting Android Emulation` window in Eclipse, it show a message, informing that Intel HAXM is being utilized.

Comment: AlwaysOn assures you it won't be off.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your emulator is running with HAXM, you'll see output like this in your run console in Android Studio, with the relevant line being the "HAX is working" bit:

```
Waiting for device.
/Users/sbarta/sdk/tools/emulator -avd x86-API10 -netspeed full -netdelay none

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
Device connected: emulator-5554
```

[image]

Or, according to Intel's official [Installation Instructions for Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows):

> To verify that Intel HAXM is running, open a Command Prompt window with administrator privileges (Run as Administrator) and execute the following command:
>
> ```
> sc query intelhaxm
> ```
>
> If Intel HAXM is working, the command will show a status message indicating that the state is: "4 RUNNING".

Comment: Interesting, for some reason, I don't get the `HAX is working and emulator runs....`
Here is the output I am getting: 
`Waiting for device.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Nexus5 -netspeed full -netdelay none

Device connected: emulator-5554
Device is ready: Nexus5 [emulator-5554]
Target device: Nexus5 [emulator-5554]`

Answer (score 9):

According to [the Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#accel-check) you can run the following:

```
$ ./sdk/emulator/emulator -accel-check
```

And if you see the following you have it installed:

```
accel:
0
HAXM version 6.0.3 (3) is installed and usable.
accel
```

Comment: I got this on OSX `accel:
0
Hypervisor.Framework OS X Version 10.14
accel`

Comment: @Mahendran - I saw the same thing, I had to manually install haxm from the github page, and then run the start command from `/Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext/Contents/Resources/haxm_start.sh`, and then go into my security settings and allow intel to run

Answer (score 4):

It's really easy. just open cmd and do what I did base on below image:

[image]

If you see the response like mine, it means that the Haxm is working.

Answer (score 1):

If not running, make sure your processor is capable of running Intel HAXM.  You must have VT and ND (aka nx no execute bit) ON in BIOS.  (You can read out the nx bit from running bcdedit  as admin). But you can't have certain other VT items running (including Hyper-V or VirtualBox).
There's an article on troubleshooting Intel HAXM at software.intel.com (search on HAXM).

Comment: `nx` is set to `OptIn`
Should it be set to AlwayOn ?