# I'm using the Android emulator. How can I tell whether or not HAXM hardware acceleration is working?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, haxm

I want to run the Android emulator, and I want it to run as fast as possible.

I've installed the Android SDK.  I've also installed HAXM (the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager).  How can I tell whether or not HAXM is working?

Note:  I haven't installed Android Studio — I've merely installed Google's "SDK Tools Only" package.  If you have Android Studio installed, please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252302) instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out if Android Studio actually uses Intel HAXM accelerator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252302/how-to-find-out-if-android-studio-actually-uses-intel-haxm-accelerator)

Comment: @Cristiana214: This is not a duplicate. I don't have Android Studio installed — I've merely installed Google's "SDK Tools Only" package. And so I don't _have_ a run console window. As for `sc query intelhaxm`, I don't trust the output. I prefer to rely on output which comes directly from the emulator itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have already have downloaded and installed three things:

1. the Android SDK
2. an Android system image
3. HAXM

You must also have used the Android AVD Manager to create a new AVD.

Open up a command prompt and start the Android emulator.  In my case, I can use:

`C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd j`

(On your PC, the command line will be different.)

Now the emulator will start.  If HAXM is working, you will see something like:

```
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
```

If HAXM is not working, you will instead see something like:

```
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
```